# How to apply multiple if condition on a series and get the results in a new column

Tags: python-3.x

I want to apply multiple `if` conditions on a series and get the results in a new column, please help me. I have the following dictionary:

```
cardinal_Temp = ["Tbas_veg", "Topt1_veg", "Topt2_veg","Tmax_veg"]
wheat_CardTemp_vegetative = [4, 22, 28, 38]
Veg_CardTemp= dict(zip(cardinal_Temp, wheat_CardTemp_vegetative))
```

And a daily temperature `list` with more than 400 values as:

```
Tmean= Date_Tmean["Tmean"]
```

How to script the `if` condition below and get the results in a new column?

```
if ((Tmean>Veg_CardTemp["Tbas_veg"]) and (Tmean<Veg_CardTemp["Topt1_veg"]):
    Temfunction = (Tmean-Veg_CardTemp["Tbas_veg"])/(Veg_CardTemp["Topt1_veg"]-Veg_CardTemp["Tbas_veg"])
elif ((Veg_CardTemp["Topt1_veg"]<=Tmean) and (Tmean<=Veg_CardTemp["Topt2_veg"])):   
    Tempfunction = 1
elif ((Veg_CardTemp["Topt2_veg"]<Tmean) and (Tmean<Veg_CardTemp["Tmax_veg"])):
    Tempfunction = (Veg_CardTemp["Tmax_veg"]-Tmean)/(Veg_CardTemp["Tmax_veg"]-Veg_CardTemp["Topt2_veg"])
elif (Tmean<=Veg_CardTemp["Tbas_veg"]) or (Tmean>=Veg_CardTemp["Tmax_veg"])):
    Tempfunction = 0
    Tempfunction = df[]
```

And how to get a final list with the results of all the `if` conditions above?

I tried the above script many times and I get an error or an empty list.

Comment: Which error do you have?

Comment: A wrong calculation I got (looks like it did not apply if) When i used:for Temp in Tmean:
 if (any(Tmean>Veg_CardTemp["Tbas_veg"]) and any(Tmean<Veg_CardTemp["Topt1_veg"])):
      Temfunction = [(Tmean-Veg_CardTemp["Tbas_veg"])/(Veg_CardTemp["Topt1_veg"]-Veg_CardTemp["Tbas_veg"])]    
print("func:", Temfunction)

Comment: and when i used :for Temp in Tmean:
 if (all(Tmean>Veg_CardTemp["Tbas_veg"]) and all(Tmean<Veg_CardTemp["Topt1_veg"])):
      Temfunction = [(Tmean-Veg_CardTemp["Tbas_veg"])/(Veg_CardTemp["Topt1_veg"]-Veg_CardTemp["Tbas_veg"])]
      print("func:", Temfunction), I get an error as NameError: name 'Temfunction' is not defined